# Spring MVC: @PathVariable form

Tags: java, spring

I have a data base which contains some items. I want to create a form which edits item with some id. I did it, form opens fine. Adress is /itemproject/edit_item/{id} Problems start when I'm trying to activate POST method. Instead of directing me to page with item list (/itemproject/view_items) programm sends me to /itemproject/edit_item/edit_item. itemproject is context path (for example).

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/edit_item/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String editItem(@PathVariable("id") Integer id, Model model) {
    Item item;
    item = dbService.findItem(item).get(0);
    model.addAttribute("item", item);
    return "edit_item";
}
@RequestMapping(value = "/edit_item/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String editItemComplete(@PathVariable("id") Integer id, @ModelAttribute("item") Item item, Model model) {
    dbService.updateItem(item);
    model.addAttribute("items",dbService.findAllItems());
    return "view_items";
}
```

dbService works with data base.

I want that programm sent me to list of all items after ediding chosen item and updating it in database.
Here is example of edit form (url: /itemproject/edit_item/{id}

```
<spring:url value="edit_item" var="formURL"/>
            <form:form action="${formURL}"
                       method="post" cssClass="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2"
                       modelAttribute="item"
                       >
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="item-stuff">Stuff</label>
                    <form:input id="item-stuff" 
                                cssClass="form-control"
                                path="stuff"/>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Edit item</button>
            </form:form>
```

This is how my item list page looks (url: /itemproject/view_items)

```
<body>
<table class="table table-hover">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>Stuff</th>
                </tr>
                <c:forEach items="${items}" var="item">
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="/itemproject/item/${item.id}">${item.stuff}</a></td>
                    </tr>            
                </c:forEach>
            </tbody>
        </table>
</body>
```

Comment: How are you calling your endpoints? Can you share some curl or js code that you are using?

Comment: @bart.s I don't use any javascript, can you tell me what files/code exactly should I share?

Comment: Please share html form code.

Comment: done, content of jsp pages in description

Answer (score 0):

From Spring docs:

> In Spring MVC you can use the `@PathVariable` annotation on a method
>   argument to bind it to the value of a **URI** template variable

That means that `@PathVariable` annotation is suitable when you use the GET method because when you use GET method you can pass your query string.

Instead, try to use `@RequestBody` in order to try to bind your POST HTTP body message to your parameter

For example:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/edit_item", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String editItemComplete(@RequestBody String body) {
    //in here you'll have to pull the body content
    return "view_items";
}
```

Let's say that you're sending an Integer id on HTTP POST body, then you can pull the data from the body like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/edit_item", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String editItemComplete(@RequestBody String body) {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        idJson = objectMapper.readTree(body).path("id").asInt();
    } catch (IOException e) {           
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "view_items";
}
```

assuming that you're sending json from client to service.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do this please?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get the idea how do I do this, maybe some more details please? Maybe some more examples?

Comment: This is the example. Do you know how to use Jackson? in order to handle json messages.

Comment: 1. I edit chosen item, it means this item is in my database. Url contains item's id, so I can find this item in database. 2. I put found item in edit form (model attribute), id should stay safe. 3. I get my item with changed stuff back, id is the same, right?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than loading the items and returning the `view_items` template, you can return `"redirect:/itemproject/view_items"` and that will cause your handler for `view_items` to be invoked, which will load the items etc.

Comment: My return should look like this? return "redirect:itemproject/view_items";

Comment: What you're doing looks right otherwise. I suspect the issue is related to confusing return values and spring having trouble figuring out how to route the request

Comment: HTTP Status 400, The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.